# Nice applications of Liouville's theorem

Tags: riemannian-geometry, big-list

I need a big list of nice-looking and simple applications of Liouville's theorem on geodesic flow in Riemannian geometry.

*Please help.*

**Examples:**

- A Riemannian manifold with finite volume does not admit a strictly convex function.
- If $M$ is a closed $m$-dimensional Riemannian manifold and $\mathrm{Sc}_M\ge \mathrm{Sc}_{\mathbb S^m}$ then injectivity radius of $M$ is at most $\pi$.

Comment: How about Section E [**here**](http://www.www.colin-baxter.com/academic/bib/downloads/joyce74.pdf#13)? (Citation: Joyce, W. B. (1974). Classical-particle description of photons and phonons. *Physical Review D, 9* (12), 3234.)

Answer (score 1):

Recall that Hopf and Green showed that integral of scalar curvature on a closed manifold without $conjugate$ points is non-positive. For the proof they used the fact that geodesic flow on unit tangent bundle preserves a volume

Their result is in the following lecture note : 
http://people.math.sc.edu/howard/Notes/hopf_note.pdf

Comment: By the way, do you know a reference to the second statement in my question?

Comment: I do not know a reference to the second statement